# avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0xyy ... where to find the response values?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, error

Last week I retried some of my Arduinos and one Mega was working without a problem, but two Uno's didn't work anymore. The error I got was something like:

```
avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0xyy
```

Where yy where all different kind of values (I cannot copy/paste it as I'm not near the Arduino's).

Does anybody know where to find a document what the response values mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't mean anything.

AVRDude sends a packet, and expects a certain response. When it gets something that it's not expecting it tells you it's "out of sync", and tells you what the actual response was it got. That is, what byte it received over the serial port.  That could be something that your sketch is sending, or complete garbage if you're communicating with a floating serial input, or anything at all.

Comment: Thanks, no wonder I couldn't found an 'error table'  ... I would hope it would mean something more useful ... in that case I try it on another computer and otherwise I have some dead Uno's.

Comment: Are they real ones? Or the dreaded CH340G?

Comment: One is a real one (even with a removable DIP Atmel) and the other is a CH340G.

Comment: Step one of diagnosis is to try a loopback test. Hold the board in RESET, and connect pin 0 to pin 1. Try and communicate and see if what you send is echoed back.

Comment: Good advice thanks ... I will try it (probably in weekend, not much home until that time).